# Vue project cannot resolve '@'

Tags: vue.js

My vue-cli version is 4.5.15, but it cannot resolve @ as ./src and all paths using '@' are not found. Why did this happen and how could I solve it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: did you write it with the /component? like `import Footer from '@/layout/Footer'`? I think you can't import a folder with multiple components, or am I wrong?

Comment: I have known what the problem is. It's because I used 'Index.vue' as the name before and git is insensitive to capital. So it cannot find the path.
Vue has supported 
```
import xxx from "@/xxx"
```
if the name of your file you want to import is "index.vue".

Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have known what the problem is. It's because I used 'Index.vue' as the name before and git is insensitive to capital. So it cannot find the path.
Vue has supported

```
import xxx from "@/xxx"
```

if the name of your file you want to import is "index.vue".
[image]
Thanks a lot for your answers!

Answer (score 4):

Your statement tries to import a file which does not exist: `import Layout from '@/layout'` would work with `layout.vue` or `layout/index.js`, neither of which is present.

To fix this, you can either import the single components with their full path (as mentioned in @wittgenstein's comment): `import Footer from '@/layout/Footer'`

Or you can create `layout/index.js` which exposes all components inside the directory:

```js
import Footer from './Footer.vue'
import Header from './Header.vue'
// ...

export default {
  Footer, Header, // ...
}
```

Then you can import components like that: `import { Footer, Header } from '@/layout'`

Comment: layout.vue won't necessarily work, in some setups .vue extension is required in import

Comment: I have known what the problem is. It's because I used 'Index.vue' as the name before and git is insensitive to capital. So it cannot find the path.
Vue has supported 
```
import xxx from "@/xxx"
```
if the name of your file you want to import is "index.vue".

Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to import a folder, you will have to import a single file from the layout folder:

```
import Footer from "@/Layout/Footer.vue"
import Header from "@/Layout/Header.vue"
import Index from "@/Layout/Index.vue"
import Sidebar from "@/Layout/Sidebar.vue"
import Sidebar2 from "@/Layout/Sidebar2.vue"
```

If you want to import every file, you will have to this all manually, because you cannot import a folder.

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: I have known what the problem is. It's because I used 'Index.vue' as the name before and git is insensitive to capital. So it cannot find the path. Vue has supported ``` import xxx from "@/xxx" ``` if the name of your file you want to import is "index.vue". Thanks a lot for your answer!